# Jquery global variable assignment and using in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I have a global variable listId(refer the below code) declared with a default value and then I am assigning it inside the     jq("#nav1 li a").click(function()  But once any of the other javascript function call takes place after this one, the listId does not reflect the changed value, instead its just the default value assigned during declaration. How can I make it reflect the changed values?

thanks

```
listId = 'x';
var jq=jQuery.noConflict();// for avoiding conflict


jq("#nav1").click(function(){
  alert(this.id);
  listId = this.id; //this.id is displayed in alert message

 });

function pageSwitch(){
 alert('on change id : '+listId);
 //when called after the click function, this does not reflect changed values
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps declare listID as a variable? `var listID = 'x';`

Comment: [Works fine for me; see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/qDCT9/#base).

Comment: also I'm not sure where you are making the call but it's a good practice to define the function that you are calling above the call

Answer (score 0):

The code you supplied worked for me. The listId variable was successfully changed to "nav1". I've written up a little test script, which changes listId to the div's id onClick, and then uses a function to change it back to "x". It works every time. [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/GeorgeK/87rmR/21/) to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guyz for the help..actually the function was invoked on click of an h:commandLink..so each time the page got reloaded and so did the js functions...I just used the a4j:commandLink and it worked fine...I should have presented the full picture..Sorry for that..will take care next time.