# global variable in javascript is not changed after being used in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

The value of global variable var img_id = 2; is changed in click function. Later it might be used in another function,  I want the changed value of that variable in case the click function is used before buttons function. But it still shows value as 2 even if clicked function is used before it.

```js
function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('mapButtons')) {

                if (document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('modelButtons').style.display = 'none';     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('mapButtons').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('modelButtons').style.display = 'block';
     
                }
            }
}
function flip() {
    $('.side').toggleClass('rotated');
}

window.img_id = 2;

$(function() {
    $('area').mouseover(function() {
         imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
       // $('#demo').text("Mouseover for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',true)
            .css('z-index',2);
    }).mouseout(function() {
         imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
      //  $('#mi').text("Mouseout for "+imgid);
        $('#'+imgid)
            .toggleClass('invert',false)
            .css('z-index',1);
    }).click(function() {
     imgid=$(this).data('imgid');
    //$('#demo').text("click for "+imgid);

    $('.pressed').removeClass('pressed');
   img_id= imgid;
  //  $('#d').text("new function "+img_id);
    $('#'+imgid)
        .toggleClass('pressed')
        .css('z-index',2);
});
});


$(function() {
 img = img_id;
 $('#d').text("new function "+img_id);
  //var img = 2;
  var min = 2;
  var max = 12;

  $('.prevButton').on('click',function(e) {
    if (img > min) {
       removeAllBorders();
        img--;
        $('#' + img).toggleClass('pressed');
    }
  });

  $('.nextButton').on('click',function(e) {
     if (img < max) {
       removeAllBorders();
       img++;
       $('#' + img).toggleClass('pressed');
     }
  });

  function removeAllBorders() {
     $('img').removeClass('pressed');
  }
});
```

```css
#container img {position: absolute;}

img.invert {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}
img.pressed {
    filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
}

.side {
 position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.side.rotated {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}


#mapButtons { position:absolute;top:90%;}
#modelButtons {
 display: none;
  position:absolute;top:90%;
}
.block {
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   -webkit-perspective:100%;
    -moz-perspective:100%;
    -ms-perspective:100%;
    -o-perspective:100%;
    perspective:100%;   
}


#flip-button {
    background: white;
    font-family:'open sans';
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #5b5b5b;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.prevButton img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.prevButton:hover img {
opacity: .5;
}

.nextButton img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nextButton:hover img {
opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<body>
<map name="map" id="id_1">
<div id="container">
<div class="front side">
<img src="leftovers_ch01.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9;z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="2" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/fpqmClk.png" style='z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="3" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/TfhyWZs.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="4" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/mUKWK5P.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="5" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/R1JhAT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="6" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/yMGFR2V.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="7" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/rpCnGxL.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="8" class="myBorder"  src="http://i.imgur.com/FWRCUs4.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="9"  class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/Aw3NhT9.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="10" class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/gWhUtyJ.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="11"  class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/IIJqsxf.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
<img   id="12"  class="myBorder" src="http://i.imgur.com/a9UW5mj.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9; z-index:1'  usemap="#map" >
</div>

   <area  data-imgid="12"  shape="poly" coords="173,223,176,222,183,224,185,217,190,199,193,192,198,187,193,176,158,132,126,92,132,93,123,79,101,97,81,123,66,149,57,170,50,194,48,211,136,217,131,225,149,225,149,221,152,221,156,215,158,208,159,197,167,189,170,179,173,177,169,171,190,176,192,187,190,190,182,198"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="11"  shape="poly" coords="173,229,181,229,184,243,192,256,201,265,201,271,179,309,174,302,125,375,106,361,88,342,71,319,59,295,52,270,48,252,47,243,65,240,61,248,147,234,147,236,150,234,150,238,154,234,154,239,156,235,159,246,165,262,175,275,185,284,195,270,184,259,177,249,174,237,173,229"
   />

   <area  data-imgid="10"  id="ch10" coords="208,268,220,272,234,272,249,266,253,272,235,280,223,280,214,279,215,274,202,283208,298,209,295,222,297,239,296,251,293,261,288,259,293,262,290,262,296,264,294,65,298,266,295,276,310,266,309,304,389,285,398,259,404,241,406,210,407,187,402,169,398,152,390,158,373,162,380,203,273,208,268"   
   />

   <area  data-imgid="9"  class="notbutton" id="ch09" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="252,265,255,266,256,271,267,262,275,249,279,233,296,234,291,255,282,270,272,280,268,283,274,284,270,286,274,288,271,290,275,291,272,292,328,359,319,359,331,374,349,360,366,342,381,321,392,299,400,276,404,257,407,240,318,235,323,227,278,227,272,231,269,244,262,256,252,265" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="8"  class="notbutton" id="ch08" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="251,188,253,181,267,192,273,200,277,208,278,212,274,213,288,220,298,207,294,207,289,196,284,186,274,174,262,166,268,166,266,164,270,162,267,161,270,159,266,158,276,142,279,151,329,78,338,85,349,94,363,108,379,129,391,152,397,168,403,189,406,211,389,213,393,206,277,225,272,222,269,209,262,197,251,188" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="7" class="notbutton" id="ch07" class="hotspot" shape="poly" coords="247,186,248,182,251,179,239,175,228,173,216,174,206,177,199,161,213,157,225,156,239,157,254,162,254,158,256,159,257,155,258,157,259,152,260,154,292,72,296,79,302,63,286,56,263,50,242,47,213,47,188,51,166,57,149,64,188,143,179,143,201,181,208,185,218,182,236,182,247,186" 
   />

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_09" shape="poly" coords="156,234,156,226,154,222,154,226,150,223,150,226,147,224,148,227,130,227,135,220,47,213,31,223,16,212,15,226,16,236,16,243,33,254,48,243,66,240,61,248,148,233,147,236,151,234,151,237,153,234,154,239,156,234"   
   />

  <area  data-imgid="6"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_08" shape="poly" coords="173,230,173,227,180,224,184,228,180,230,173,230"   
  />   

  <area  data-imgid="6"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_07" shape="poly" coords="205,264,207,268,203,272,162,380,158,372,151,389,154,407,136,417,124,412,115,406,108,401,125,394,125,375,174,302,179,309,200,271,201,266,205,264"   
  />  

  <area  data-imgid="6"  class="notbutton" id="ch06_06" shape="poly" coords="261,288,260,291,263,290,262,295,264,293,264,297,266,295,275,309,266,309,305,389,321,397,319,415,330,412,341,405,347,400,347,379,330,374,318,359,328,359,272,292,274,291,271,289,275,288,269,287,273,284,267,284,261,288"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_05" shape="poly" coords="249,264,249,268,253,273,256,271,254,266,249,264"   
  /> 

  <area  data-imgid="6"  class="notbutton"id="ch06_04" shape="poly" coords="271,227,273,223,277,225,393,206,388,214,407,211,420,200,436,210,438,218,438,229,437,242,422,231,406,240,318,235,323,227,277,227,274,230,271,227"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_03" shape="poly" coords="256,163,262,166,267,165,265,164,269,162,266,161,269,159,266,158,276,142,279,150,329,78,329,59,344,51,333,45,323,39,316,36,300,45,303,63,296,80,292,72,260,154,259,153,259,158,256,155,257,159,254,158,256,163"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_02" shape="poly" coords="248,189,247,183,251,180,253,181,252,186,248,189"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="6" class="notbutton" id="ch06_01" shape="poly" coords="199,191,203,188,207,192,205,187,207,185,202,182,178,142,188,143,149,64,133,55,133,37,122,44,112,49,107,53,107,73,123,78,135,93,126,93,199,183,199,191"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch05_06" shape="poly" coords="16,212,31,223,47,214,50,189,55,169,62,152,70,136,81,120,92,107,105,93,118,82,123,79,107,73,107,54,91,65,73,83,57,101,45,119,36,137,27,158,20,183,17,202,16,212"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton"id="ch05_05" shape="poly" coords="108,401,125,394,125,375,112,366,97,352,83,336,69,316,61,298,54,280,49,261,47,243,33,255,16,244,20,270,27,293,34,313,45,334,57,352,71,369,88,385,108,401"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch05_04" shape="poly" coords="305,389,321,398,319,415,290,427,265,433,237,436,208,436,181,432,159,426,136,417,154,407,151,391,171,399,192,404,213,407,236,407,261,404,280,399,296,393,305,389"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch05_03" shape="poly" coords="406,240,423,231,437,242,434,264,429,285,424,302,416,320,404,341,390,360,375,376,357,391,347,399,347,380,331,374,345,363,358,350,370,336,380,323,387,309,395,294,399,279,403,265,406,247,406,240"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton"id="ch05_02" shape="poly" coords="329,77,328,58,344,52,363,66,383,85,396,101,410,123,421,144,428,164,433,182,436,199,436,210,420,200,406,211,404,191,398,169,390,149,380,131,365,110,352,97,339,86,329,77"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch05_01" shape="poly" coords="132,55,134,37,152,30,174,23,200,18,219,17,240,17,260,19,276,22,291,26,303,31,316,36,300,45,303,63,284,55,265,51,250,48,234,46,215,47,194,49,175,53,157,60,149,64,132,55"   
  /> 

   <area  data-imgid="5" class="notbutton" id="ch04_03" shape="poly" coords="195,270,185,284,174,273,166,263,160,251,157,240,156,226,158,211,163,195,174,180,177,177,174,175,191,176,192,191,188,189,178,203,173,219,173,233,177,248,185,261,195,270"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="4" class="notbutton" id="ch04_02" shape="poly" coords="202,283,215,275,214,279,223,280,234,280,245,277,257,271,265,264,273,253,278,241,280,233,296,235,290,257,283,269,276,276,267,285,251,292,235,297,220,297,210,295,209,298,202,283"   
  /> 

    <area  data-imgid="4" class="notbutton" id="ch04_01" shape="poly" coords="206,177,216,174,231,173,247,177,257,183,266,191,273,201,278,212,274,213,288,220,297,207,294,208,289,196,282,184,271,172,260,165,245,159,230,156,214,157,199,161,206,177"   
   /> 

   <area  data-imgid="2" id="ch02" shape="poly" coords="214,234,216,246,228,241,238,246,240,233,248,227,239,219,237,207,226,212,216,208,215,219,205,227,214,234"   
   /> 

    <area  data-imgid="3" id="ch03" shape="poly" coords="181,226,189,227,181,229,182,237,186,247,192,256,199,262,203,266,207,261,206,267,213,270,222,272,232,272,242,269,250,266,247,262,251,266,259,259,265,251,269,242,272,234,272,227,267,227,272,226,271,218,269,209,264,201,257,193,250,188,247,191,247,187,239,182,226,181,214,183,207,186,205,187,208,194,203,188,196,193,189,201,184,211,181,221,181,226"   
   /> 
 </map>

<div class="back side">
<img id="image1" src="blbl.png" style='position:absolute;top:8;left:9;' usemap="#map2" />
</div>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="mi"></p>
<p id="clicked"></p>
<div id = "mapButtons" >
<button class = "prevButton" type="button"><img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/PjVnMY1.png"></button>
<button id="flip-button" class = "changeButton" type="button" onclick= "flip();switchVisible();"><img id="image" src="mapButton1.png"></button>
<button class = "nextButton" type="button"><img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/sR3xfJl.png"></button>
</div> 

<div id = "modelButtons" >
<button class = "prevButton" type="button"><img id="image" src="prevButton.png"></button>
<button id="flip-button" class = "changeButton" type="button" onclick= "flip(); switchVisible();"><img id="image" src="modelButton1.png"></button>
<button class = "nextButton" type="button" ><img id="image" src="nextButton.png"></button>
</div>

 <p id="d"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: use `window.img_id = 2;` instead of `var img_id = 2;`

Comment: @JohannesJander these are the same definition for the `img_id` global variable, as it's defined at global scope

Comment: changed it, did not help. if a person has cliked on some image directly, i want the next and prev button to take id of that image and navigate from there.

Comment: @Karen the issue is that you're saving the first value of `img_id` here `var img = img_id` and this value does not change in the click callbacks. you have to use `img_id` directly in your callbacks

Comment: It should not take vales after mouseover and mouseout. I want it to store id only if user has clicked. It is like navigation. So it should take only that value if he has cliked onn that image.

Comment: @Hacketo I tried using dirrectly, that also does not help. the value remains 2 after click too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483810/jquery-global-variable-assignment-and-using-in-javascript-function how do i do this?

Comment: In the last two functions you assign img_id to img, then you manipulate img, but you never do anything with it. Is that the problem?

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex i am trying to see what id comes in img, The onclick id should come in image. so i am just printing it before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem or cause:**

The second function() block does `img = img_id` inside the main function block, which is executed once and then never again after the initial page load. It also defines some event handlers, but they all use the value of `img` which **does not change anymore**... Only the event handlers are called multiple times, but not the code that precedes them.

**Solution:**

use `img_id` directly in those event handlers.

Comment: img_id is local variable i am not able to use it in second function.

Comment: I find that hard to believe: if the function() can use `img_id` (which it seems to do), then so can the event handlers that the function() defines. Or the reverse would be true: if the event handlers cannot use it, then also the function() can't. A solution for this would then be to use `window.img_id` instead of `img_id` everywhere, as already suggested elsewhere.

Comment: I have edited the code and printed the value of img_id in the second function to see if the value changes after click. But the value remains 2

Comment: Please try replacing ALL occurences of `img_id` with `window.img_id`. In the code inside your question you changed the line of code that defines it, but not in the places where it is being used.

Comment: That too is not helping.

Comment: do i have this issue? i did not understand the solution for this.

Comment: I put everything together, did some cleanup, and managed to at least get the img_id up/down count working. Still not clear to me what it is supposed to do, too many parts are missing. But what I made of it can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3s4HmfWgFTkSnU0cUMyYVBqbUU/view?usp=sharing (press the down-arrow on top to download)

Answer (score 1):

To use a global variable, you must firstly, announce this variable with `var example`.

However, to use it inside a function you must not reannounce it like you did, since it then announce that variable in the local function only.

To use and edit a global variable in the local function, you only need to pass `example = 5;`, without reannouncing it with the "var" keyword. The only time it must be announced is in the global scope

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AmineIzumi/8w23dr1L/).
As you can see, i initialized the variables at the beginning (and removed 'window.img_id'), and it seems to be perfectly working. How have you checked your variables ?

Comment: Working on my side. I've clarified the answer, can you post the javascript you made ?

Comment: I made the changes suggested by you in the above code.

Comment: You only did it in one function, all the globally defined local variables 'var xxx = ..' must be replaced by 'xxx = ..' , except the first global one.

Comment: var img is only used in one function.

Comment: In short, this answer is meant for all the global variables, not only var img, but var img_id too, and any other. I'll edit my answer to be more clear.

Comment: It should not take vales after mouseover and mouseout. I want it to store id only if user has clicked. It is like navigation. So it should take only that value if he has cliked onn that image.

Comment: Okay, I'll post a fiddle with your code in some minutes :)

Comment: i have a navigation where image color inverrts on mouse over and mouseout and click
Now i have this navigate by arrows option too
Where if person has not cliked the navigation can start ffrom 2 to 12
but if a person has cliked on image example 3
then navigation next arrow should show 4
and so on
and previous arrow should show 2

Answer (score 1):

Remove `var img = img_id;` and just use img_id directly in the button click listeners. You assign img to img_id's value when the script is loaded, and from there on img and img_id take on separate lives...

Comment: still the value remains 2 :(